# Postgresql 9.2.1, vacuum freeze process stuck while running

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

In postgresql 9.2.1, i'm running vacuum freeze process in single user mode. suddenly, the vacuuming process got stuck in the half way through (just frozen while vacuuming some transactions).

- What would be the reasons for that vacuuming process can stuck in
  half way ?
- How can i prevent it ?

Comment: Not really a good question for SO (not programming related), but ideal for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Define *stuck*. No activity in `top` or with `strace`? Give it time!

Comment: *WARNING: database "XXXX" must be vacuumed within 997218 transactions. HINT: To avoid a database shutdown, execute a full-database VACUUM in "postgres". * While running it shows the above error and froze.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)